# Custom Sort Order Puzzler

Tags: orderby

I have a channel which searches by various custom fields and returns 4 results.

What I want to do is to order them by 1,2,3,4 etc and have a custom field to order them with to that effect. No problem there.

Where the question arises is if only 3 entries are returned - there have to be 4 as each entry equals a time: 1 - 10.00, 2 - 10.30, 3 - 11.00 and 4 - 11.30.

So we need to have a conditional to show one of these but can't actually test against one as it doesn't exist. Ie if no-one has submitted an entry for 10.00 I want it to show "AVAILABLE" or some such. Doesn't seem that easy to do....

Comment: Can I assume you trying to do this dynamically? meaning you don't know the entry ID's? Is there an entry ID for a time that should show as "Available"?

Comment: Do you have a question or are you just telling is a nice story..?

Comment: Hi Anna yes, is dynamic so don't know the IDs but have been working with the idea of having a fixed 'blank' entry to show for 'Available' which would have a known ID.

Problem is though that this would also be ordered by the custom field that has a 1.2, 3 or 4 in it and I can get it showing but it messes up the order as the ordering field is shown as: 1,2,2,3 for example (because the 'Available' field is also #2 like the user submitted field is) whereas I need:1,2,3,4.

Thanks for this though - hadn't thought of it and opens up another angle. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

EE can't show what it doesn't have. So the channel entries should not be the starting point of your quest, but i guess the timeslots should be.

I would either go for a frontend solution and let jquery (or a library like angular/knockout) solve the display problem. Or i would prepare a timeslot-list with stash and add the entries to another list and/or compare them. 
See also: https://speakerdeck.com/croxton/stash-core-principles?slide=55

Comment: I went the way of the two Stash lists - thanks for that. One for the Timeslots and one for the entries. 

Have hit a snag though as I can't get a conditional going to show the Timeslot (which is essentially a 'holder') if the corresponding entry is not there.